# Logstash 5 configure log4j logging for itself (not as plugin)

Tags: log4j, logstash

This is just for future reference since I solved it myself.

When I switched from logstash 2.x to 5.x, I was dealing with this warning (when I was runnig my logstash on this path D:\somepath\logstash-5.0.1):

```
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /somepath/logstash-5.0.1/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs to console
```

After some searching on internet and digging in ruby code (in the extracted logstash) I have found out this:

1. necessary to use **path.settings** (as mentioned many times) correctly
2. use correctly file or directory as **URL path**.

Finally I run my logstash as:

```
logstash.bat --path.settings=file://D:/somepath/logstash-5.0.1/config
```